# Quickly launch any app in KDE with a shortcut

Tags: kde, shortcuts

How can you quickly launch an app with an assigned shortcut in KDE?

System Settings → *Shortcuts and Gestures* → *Custom Shortcuts* → *Edit* → *New*

Answer (score 22):

1. Unlock Widgets.
2. Right-click in launcher and click Edit Applications...
3. Find the app you want to assign a shortcut

For example:
Click on System, and click on Konsole. Click on Advanced Tab. At the bottom you can see 
Current shortcut key, click on the button and enter the shortcut.

[image: Example]

Comment: What/where is "Unlock Widgets" and "launcher"?

Comment: Just right-click on the desktop and you will see a contextual menu with Unlock Widgets.

Comment: is there a way for 2nd call to shortcut to focus on already opened instance?

Comment: What if I just want to bring an application into focus?

Comment: Right click the "Start Menu" Icon, and "Edit Applications"

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but I don't understand why one would want to have a shortcut to launch a new instance of an application. Isn't the vastly more common case that you want to switch to an already-launched instance?

Comment: By using https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp in a command in the Custom Shortcuts pane, one can achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Just to reiterate what @HeathMatlock suggested:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then set a `Shortcut` under `Trigger`, and enter a `Command` under `Action`.

If you're not sure what the command is, maybe try:

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID | awk '{print $3}' | xargs ps -o comm= -p
```

and click on the application window. This attempts to grab the PID that created the window and passes it to `ps` to see what the command for the PID was. Not 100% reliable for example if your bashrc adds stuff to `PATH` you might find the same command won't work as a shortcut.

---

To run an application *only* if it isn't already running, I use this:

```
ps -e | grep mycommand || mycommand
```