# How to have ksysguard launched instead of just limited "System Activity"?

Tags: plasma

System Activity is annoying. It's displayed "always on top" and you can't turn off this feature. Not really convenient. Also, you can't see other tabs that are shown by default in `ksysguard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom shortcut like described in https://askubuntu.com/a/498816 answer.

For shortcut use "Ctrl + Esc" which will override default "Power Management -> Show System Activity" action.

Specify the action command:

```
bash -c "([ \"$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)\" == 'System Monitor' ] && pkill ksysguard) || (pgrep '^ksysguard$' && wmctrl -x -R ksysguard) || (ksysguard && pkill ksysguard)"
```

You need to install `xdotool` and `wmctrl` packages to make it work:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
sudo apt install wmctrl
```